# PHP eclipse Error ArticleClass cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: php

I am working with my PHP project and I have a strange problem.
To try to solve it, I have created a test file.

In this test file Eclipse tells me that "ArticleClass cannot be resolved to a type".

So I try : class_exists on this class, it tells me it exists.
I try get_declared_classes(), it tells me the class exist.

When I write $Article = new ArticleClass($Niv,$Id); no error occurs (except the error message in the editor of Eclipse). $Article is well defined.

I try to use a function of the ArticleClass : it works.
I try another function : it doesn't work even if the get_class_methods tells me that the function exists for the ArticleClass.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: The difference is that when you run the code, PHP adds in all of the included class etc.  But in the editor it is saying that in the current file, there is no reference to the actual class you want to use.  Try adding a `use` statement with the fully qualified name of the class.

Comment: The main problem is in fact when I run the php file. It recongnize the $Article, when I display the methods available with get_class_methods, I can see the method ActuCharge I want to use but when I write $Article->ActuCharge(), it complains that the method doesn't exist... Why ?

Comment: Have you added a `use` line in the source file where it's complaining about it?

Comment: The line was already in the file